# BigQuery PARSE_DATE cannot parse year followed by a colon : character

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a weirdly formatted timestamp: `23/Jan/2019:23:35:37 +0330`
When I try using `(safe.)PARSE_DATE(%d/%b/%Y, weirdTimestampColumn)` the parsing fails.
I was able to trace down the failure to the colon after the year by manual datetime string testing, e.g.:

The following works

`SELECT safe.PARSE_DATE("%d/%b/%Y", "01/Jan/2001") as datetime`

The following do not:

```
SELECT safe.PARSE_DATE("%d/%b/%Y", "01/Jan/2001:1") as datetime
SELECT safe.PARSE_DATE("%d/%b/%Y:", "01/Jan/2001:1") as datetime
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the expectation from the PARSE_`type` functions is that the format string accounts for every character in the input string. The extra part that you don't need will have to be described in the format string as well.

You can either do:

```
SELECT DATE(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z", "23/Jan/2019:23:35:37 +0330")) as date
```

or you can strip the extra parts (you need to deal with the DAY part if the first day of a month is 1 instead of 01)

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE("%d/%b/%Y", LEFT("23/Jan/2019:23:35:37 +0330", 11)) as date
```

Comment: Thank you! The following confirmed as a working sql:

```
SELECT safe.PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z", "23/Jan/2019:23:35:37 +0330") as datetime

Output:

2019-01-23 20:05:37 UTC

In a select from a table statement:

SELECT 
  time
  , PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z", time) as datetime
from `alerts-357619.alerts.access-log` limit 100